# Is it possible to use several attributes in a jQuery selector?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I'm new to jQuery.  I know you can use `$('.selector [attribute=value]')` to select objects in the dom but is it possible to use several atributes at once?

For example:

```
$('.selector [attribute=value], [attribute2=value2]')
```

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/multiple-attribute-selector/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax is:

```
$(".selector[attribute=value][attribute2=value2]")
```

But if you find yourself having to create complex attribute filters, using the `filter()` function might be a cleaner alternative:

```
$(".selector").filter(function () {
    var $el = $(this);
    return $el.attr("attribute") === value &&
           $el.attr("attribute2") === value2;
})
```

Answer (score 4):

Yes. How you do it depends on what you want to do. If you want to match either attribute you use the comma operator and complete selectors:

```
Like $('.selector [attribute=value], .selector [attribute2=value2]')
```

If you want to the elements to match both attributes, you just stack them after each other:

```
Like $('.selector [attribute=value][attribute2=value2]')
```

---

Note also that space is an operator, so the selector `.selector [attribute=value]` matches elements with the given attribute inside an element with the class `selector`, while the selector `.selector[attribute=value]` matches elements both with the class `selector` and the given attribute.

Comment: You better note about the space between the class and the attribute. It's probably a mistake...

Answer (score 3):

it depends what you want:

selects elements with both attributes:

```
$('.selector[attribute=value][attribute2=value]')
```

selects elements with either attribute:

```
$('.selector[attribute=value], .selector[attribute2=value]')
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.selector [attribute=value][attribute2=value2]')
```

Source: [Multiple Attribute Selector](http://api.jquery.com/multiple-attribute-selector/)

Comment: Downvoter, care to explain?  I don't see anything wrong here.

Answer (score 0):

You sure can.  The selector you have suggested will select two groups, `.selector [attribute=value]` and `[attribute2=value2]`.  If you want both, `$('.selector [attribute=value][attribute2=value2]')` is the right syntax.

Answer (score 0):

Given this HTML as a sample :

```
<a rel="foo">Stack Overflow</a>
<a class="bar">Server Fault</a>
```

This should do the trick :

```
$("a[rel='foo'], a[class='bar']")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [.filter()](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) to do this.

```
$('li').filter("[attribute1=value1]")
       .filter("[attribute2=value2]");
```